# How can I force ESXi running on a laptop to run at the full processor speed?

Tags: vmware, esxi, intel-core-i7, cpu-throttling

I have a Dell Latitude 5520 with an [Intel Core i7-1185G7 3.0 GHz processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/208664/intel-core-i71185g7-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz-with-ipu.html).  This laptop has been relegated to homelab duties, running VMware ESXi 8.0u1.

I recently put it to work for a specific project for which a bit of processing power was required, at which point I noticed that each core is only running at 1.8GHz.  Looking at the host, it reports a total of 7.2GHz available, (4 cores * 1.8GHz).

Here's what I've tried so far (most settings applied in isolation):

- Disabled Intel SpeedStep
- Disabled Intel SpeedShift
- Disabled Intel TurboBoost
- Disabled C-State control
- Changed the power policy within ESXi to High Performance

...but I can never unlock the full speed of all the cores.

It's worth noting that the 1.8GHz core speed is the "current speed" reported by the BIOS as well (with max and min reported as 4.8GHz and 0.4GHz).  This leads me to believe that 1.8GHz is a default "baseline" speed that the OS is responsible for controlling (though I'm surprised I can't seem to bypass this at the BIOS level).

Ultimately, this isn't a massive letdown as I can live with the tradeoff of lower power consumption, but would appreciate any advice on how to force this to run at the quoted 3.0GHz (or behave in the dynamic way it would under Windows)!

Comment: Shouldn't turbo boost make the processor run _faster_?

Comment: Is Speed Step merely running as fast as it needs for this app?

Comment: @oxou - Indeed, but it would be remiss of me to omit this from my testing.

Comment: @John - In this instance the CPU is virualised and presented to the app, so the demand of the app itself is less likely to impact the demand on the system due to the way the scheduler performs time-slicing.  But I'm also neither a CPU or VMware ESXi engineer!

Comment: ESXi is a bare metal App and not made to run as a virtual system.

Comment: @oxou: For fewer than all cores (e.g. boost 2 cores out of 4) and for a short period of time (until it reaches thermal limits).

Comment: It is (in my experience) the wrong App for the machine. Try VMware Workstation instead.

Comment: How many vCPUs are you assigning to the VM? _(I'm making the assumption ESXi is running as the host OS and not within a VM)_

Comment: @John Why do you think the OP is not running ESXi on bare metal? Also, if you do not need a host OS under the VM's why would you want to take resources away from the actual applications by using VMware Workstation?

Comment: The earlier comments on this were confusing. VMware Workstation works better on a workstation machine than ESX